# PHP catch attribute value in xml

Tags: php, xml

I am having difficulty capturing values for `Size`, `Type`, `Series`, and `Speed` without using a `foreach`.

This is an example xml :

```
  <product version="1.4" productId="{719cc26f-754f-45b6-b169-9cdf48f3f6ef}" groupId="CORSAIR" codeId="CMD16GX3M2A1866C9">
      <name>Памет Corsair DDR3, 1866MHz 16GB 2 x 8GB DIMM, Unbuffered, 9-10-9-27, DOMINATOR® Platinum, 1.5V</name>
      <vendor>Corsair</vendor>
      <propertyGroup propertyGroupId="{2913e3e7-159e-4c7f-a1ba-f34f0132b6ee}">
        <propertyGroupName>RAM</propertyGroupName>
        <property propertyId="1" type="Enum" name="Size">
          <value valueId="17">2 x 8 GB</value>
        </property>
        <property propertyId="2" type="Enum" name="Type">
          <value valueId="4">DDR3 DIMM KIT</value>
        </property>
        <property propertyId="3" type="Enum" name="Series">
          <value valueId="15">XMS3 Dominator Platinum</value>
        </property>
        <property propertyId="4" type="Enum" name="Speed">
          <value valueId="21">1866 MHz</value>
        </property>
        <property propertyId="5" type="Enum" name="Latency">
          <value valueId="17">9 - 10 - 9 - 27</value>
        </property>
        <property propertyId="6" type="Enum" name="Heat Spreader">
          <value valueId="1">Yes</value>
        </property>
        <property propertyId="7" type="Boolean" name="Fan">
          <value valueId="0">No</value>
        </property>
        <property propertyId="8" type="Enum" name="Package">
          <value valueId="4">2 x 240 DIMM</value>
        </property>
        <property propertyId="9" type="Enum" name="Warranty">
          <value valueId="11">Limited Lifetime</value>
        </property>
      </propertyGroup>
      <propertyGroup propertyGroupId="{3f2c48a7-b185-4fad-bd20-7d0c50502645}">
        <propertyGroupName>Product : Common</propertyGroupName>
        <property propertyId="2" type="Text" name="Партиден номер">
          <value valueId="0">CMD16GX3M2A1866C9</value>
        </property>
        <property propertyId="4" type="URL" name="Уебстраница">
          <value valueId="0">http://www.corsair.com/en/dominator-platinum-with-corsair-link-connector-1-5v-16-gb-dual-channel-ddr3-memory-kit-cmd16gx3m2a1866c9.html</value>
        </property>
      </propertyGroup>
      <image type="other">http://www.test.bg/resources/CMD16GX3M2A1866C9.jpg?guid={6d96d815-36cb-46ea-a82c-4e29910e6f1b}</image>
    </product>
```

This is what I've tried:

```
$xml= simplexml_load_file('example.xml');

$Size = $xml->propertyGroup[0]->attributes()[Size]->value;
$Type = $xml->propertyGroup[0]->attributes()[Type]->value;
$Speed = $xml->propertyGroup[0]->attributes()[Speed]->value;
```

Comment: rather than having others write code for you, please edit your question and show what you have tried so far and describe what you got in relation to what you want to get.

Comment: Please refer to http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for guidelines on how to ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

The `<propertyGroup>` has multiple `<property>` element nodes, so you should index into 'property' to get the element node that you are looking for.

The values you are looking for are in the 'name' attribute.

The 'name' attribute is of type [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php). If you want your variable to contain the text content you can use the `__toString()` method on it or you can cast it to a string `(string)` using [Type Juggling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)

For example:

```
$Size = (string)$xml->propertyGroup[0]->property[0]->attributes()->name;
$Type = (string)$xml->propertyGroup[0]->property[1]->attributes()->name;
$Speed = (string)$xml->propertyGroup[0]->property[3]->attributes()->name;
$Series = (string)$xml->propertyGroup[0]->property[2]->attributes()->name;
```

You can also use [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) of you want to search for an attribute value:

```
$elements = $xml->xpath('//propertyGroup/property[@name="Size"]');
$Size = $elements[0]->value->__toString();
echo $Size;
```

If you directly want to get '2 x 8 GB', you can also get it like this:

```
$Size = (string)$xml->propertyGroup[0]->property[0]->value;
echo $Size;
```

Both will result in:

> 2 x 8 GB

Comment: What does it mean (string)?
(string) = ?
Is it possible to catch by name? Because in some cases there is no "Series" and then property[2] is wrong.

Comment: This examle:
 $Size = (string)$xml->propertyGroup[0]->property[0]->attributes()->name;
Rerurn "Size".
I want to return "2 x 8 GB".

Comment: You can use it like this: `$Size = (string)$xml->propertyGroup[0]->property[0]->value;` I've also added an example how to use SimpleXMLElement `xpath` to search for an attribute value.